# F# CSV Type Provider : how to ignore some rows?

Tags: csv, f#, f#-data

I am a beginner and starting to use FSharp.Data library
http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html

```
let rawfile = CsvFile.Load("mydata.csv")
for row in rawfile.Rows do
       let d = System.DateTime.Parse (row.GetColumn("Date"))
       let p = float (row.GetColumn("Close Price"))
       printfn "%A %A" d p
       price_table.[BTC].Add (d,p)
```

I have a csv file whose last lines I would like to ignore because
they are something like "this data was produced by ...."

by the way, even if i delete those lines, save the file, when i reopen again those cells reappear... sticky ones !!!

Comment: I don't think the CsvProvider skips rows at the end but you can always use `rows.Take(x)`, or apply a filter to get the necessary data. Three more comments: 1. you might want to try using the [Csv Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) to correctly type the columns, 2. it has an `IgnoreErrors=true` option that will skip over the nonconforming rows, 3. You might want to try [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/)  that has an IgnoreFirst and IgnoreLast option, if you decorate an F# record with` [<CLIMutable>]` Filehelpers works very well.

Comment: Neither the CSV Provider or Parser (which you are using) are able to skip the last rows. Try setting the `ignoreErrors` parameter to ignore the last lines.

Answer (score 0):

There's an overload for `CsvFile.Load` that takes a `TextReader`-derived parameter.

If you know how many lines to skip, you can create a `StreamReader` on the file, you can skip lines with `ReadLine`.

```
use reader = StreamReader("mydata.csv")
reader.ReadLine() |> ignore
reader.ReadLine() |> ignore
let rawfile = CsvFile.Load(reader)
```

Comment: This skips only the first lines, for which CsvFile already has an option `skipRows`.

Comment: A forward-only text reader can't skip footer lines because it can't know how many lines are left

Comment: Oops. Should have read the question better. Yes, you'd need a custom reader that read-ahead and marked the end before the blank lines, or read all the lines into an array, slice off the last lines and put them back together into one string for a StringReader instance instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with loading whole scv into memory, then you can simply reverse your rows, skip what you want and then (optionally) reverse back.

Example:

```
let skipNLastValues (n:int) (xs:seq<'a>) =
    xs
    |> Seq.rev
    |> Seq.skip n
    |> Seq.rev

for i in (skipNLastValues 2 {1..10}) do
    printfn "%A" i
```